# Nginx; use blog.example.com to access example.com/blog

Tags: redirect, nginx, subdomain

I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of a day.

I want to be able to use a subdomain to access a directory/file on the server, without changing the clients URL. Forgive me for using incorrect technical terms.

I can do this:

```
if ($host = 'blog.example.com') {
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://example.com/blog/  permanent;
}
```

Except that changes the URL. If someone could point me in the right direction for this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup an nginx server configuration for the sub domain, set it's document_root to be the `/path/to/www/htdocs/blog`  and it should handle it just fine.

```
server {
    server_name blog.example.com;
    root  /path/to/www/htdocs/blog;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    # any other configuration needed for the sub domain.
}
```

Should do it.